# Calculate an image histogram with repa

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm loading an RGB image from disk with `JuicyPixels-repa`. Unfortunately the Array representation of the image is `Array F DIM3 Word8` where the inner dimension is the RGB pixels. That's a bit incompatibe with existing `repa` imageprocessing algorithms where an RGB image is `Array U DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)`.

I want to calculate the RGB histograms of the image, I'm searching a function with the Signature:

```
type Hist = Array U DIM1 Int
histogram:: Array F DIM3  Word8 -> (Hist, Hist, Hist)
```

how can I fold my 3d array to get a 1d array for each colorchannel?

Edit:

The main problem is not that I'm not able to convert from `DIM3` to `DIM2` for each channel (easy done with slicing). The problem is that I have to iterate the source image `DIM2` or `DIM3` and have to accumulate to an `DIM1` array of a different `Shape` `(Z:.256)` **and** extent.
So I can't use repa's `foldS` as it reduces the dimension by one, but with the same extent.

I also experimented with `traverse` but it iterates over the extent of the destination image, providing a function to get pixels from the source image, that would lead to very inefficient code, counting the same pixels for each colorvalue.

A good way would be a simple folding over a `Vector` with the histogram type as accumulator, but unfortunately I have no `U` (unboxed) or `V` (vector) based array, from which I can efficiently get a `Vector`. I have an `Array F` (foreign pointer).

Comment: What have you tried? (Could you do it if the array had type `Array U DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)`? If so, can you write a conversion function `Array U DIM3 Word8 -> Array U DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)`?)

Comment: I'll try to look at this tomorrow.  In the mean time, if there are basic conversions between image representations that you think would be useful in JP-repa then feel free to send a patch.

Comment: @FalcoHirschenberger Did you ever get Otsu thresholding done?  I'd like it but I'd like to avoid any duplicate work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found a few minutes.  Below, I cover four solutions and have made the worst solutions (the middle two, involving O(n) data conversion) really easy for you.

**Lets Acknowledge the Dumb Solution**

It's reasonable to start with the obvious.  You could use `Data.List.foldl` to traverse the rows and columns, building up your histograms from initial zero arrays (untested/partial code follows):

```
foldl (\(histR, histG, histB) (row,col) ->
            let r = arr ! (Z:.row:.col:.0)
                g = arr ! (Z:.row:.col:.1)
                b = arr ! (Z:.row:.col:.2)
            in (incElem r histR, incElem g histG, incElem b histB)
         (zero,zero,zero)
         [ (row,col) | row <- [0..nrRow-1], col <- [0..nrCol-1] ]
 ...
 where (Z:.nrRow:.nrCol:._) = extent arr
```

I'm not sure how efficient this will be, but suspect that it will do too much bounds checking.  Switching to unsafeIndex should do reasonably, assuming the delayed arrays, `hist*`, do well due to however you'd pick to implement `incElem`.

**You Can Build the Array You Want**

Using `traverse` you can actually convert JP-Repa style arrays into `DIM2` arrays with tuples for elements:

```
main = do
    let arr = R.fromFunction (Z:.a:.b:.c) (\(Z:.i:.j:.k) -> i+j-k)
        a =4 :: Int
        b = 4 :: Int
        c= 4 :: Int
        new = R.traverse arr
                       (\(Z:.r:.c:._) -> Z:.r:.c) -- the extent
                       (\l idx -> (l (idx:.0)
                                  ,l (idx:.1)
                                  ,l (idx :. 2)))
    print (R.computeS new :: R.Array R.U DIM2 (Int,Int,Int))
```

Could you point me to the body of code you talked about that uses this format?  It would be simple to patch JP-Repa to include a function of this type.

**You can build the Unboxed Vector You Mentioned**

You mentioned an easy solution is to fold over unboxed vectors, but lamented that JP-repa doesn't provide an unboxed array.  Luckily, conversion is simple:

```
toUnboxed :: Img a -> VU.Vector Word8
toUnboxed = R.toUnboxed . R.computeUnboxedS . R.delay . imgData
```

**We Could Patch Repa**

This is really only a problem because Repa doesn't have what I consider a normal `traverse` function.  Repa's traverse is more of an array construction that happens to provide an indexing function into another array.  We want traverse in the form:

```
newTraverse :: Array r sh e -> a -> (a -> sh -> e -> a) -> a
```

but of coarse this is actually just a malformed fold.  So lets rename it and reorder the arguments:

```
foldAllIdxS :: (sh -> a - > e -> a) -> a -> Array r sh e -> a
```

which contrasts nicely with the (preexisting) `foldAllS` operation:

```
foldAllS :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Array r sh a -> a
```

Notice how our new fold has two critical characteristics.  The result type is not required to match the element type, so we could start with a tuple of Histograms.  Second, our version of fold passes the index, which allows you to select which histogram in the tuple to update (if any).

**You can lazily use the latest JuicyPixels-Repa**

To acquire your preferred Repa array format, or to acquire an unboxed vector, you can just use the newly uploaded JuicyPixels-Repa-0.6.

```
someImg <- readImage path :: IO (Either String (Img RGBA))
let img = either (error "Blah") id someImg
    uvec = toUnboxed img
    tupleArr = collapseColorChannel img
```

Now you can fold over the vector or use the tuple array directly, as you originally desired.

I also took an ugly stab at fleshing out the first, horribly naive, solution:

```
histograms :: Img a -> (Histogram, Histogram, Histogram, Histogram)
histograms (Img arr) =
    let (Z:.nrRow:.nrCol:._) = R.extent arr
        zero = R.fromFunction (Z:.256) (\_ -> 0 :: Word8)
        incElem idx x = RU.unsafeTraverse x id (\l i -> l i + if i==(Z:.fromIntegral idx) then 1 else 0)
    in Prelude.foldl (\(hR, hG, hB, hA) (row,col) ->
             let r = R.unsafeIndex arr (Z:.row:.col:.0)
                 g = R.unsafeIndex arr (Z:.row:.col:.1)
                 b = R.unsafeIndex arr (Z:.row:.col:.2)
                 a = R.unsafeIndex arr (Z:.row:.col:.3)
             in (incElem r hR, incElem g hG, incElem b hB, incElem a hA))
          (zero,zero,zero,zero)
          [ (row,col) | row <- [0..nrRow-1], col <- [0..nrCol-1] ]
```

I'm too wary of the performance of this code (3 traversals per index... I must be tired) to throw it into JP-Repa, but if you find it works well then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your awsome answer. I'll try your suggestions asap. I try to implement the Otsu automatic thresholding algorithm. Concerning your Question, the algorithms in `repa-algorithms` represent a mutichannel image in the form `Array U DIM2 a` and provide pixel conversion functions of the form `rgb8OfFloat :: (Float, Float, Float) -> (Word8, Word8, Word8)`.